# keras IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I'm encoding a keras layer named A where I need Two tensor a,b . How should I do to fix the inputs [a,b] to get a correct return (the return of A are also tow tesor)?

def get_model(latent_dim):

```
# Input variables
u = Input(shape=(k,), dtype='float32', name = 'u]')
i = Input(shape=(k,), dtype='float32', name = 'i]')

LA=A(latent_dim)
list = A([u ,i])
u_return = list_co[-2]
i_return = list_co[-1]
```

encoding environment : For simply , I just set A as flows:

class A(latent_dim):
     def call(inputs):
         m = inputs[0]
         n = inputs[1]
         return [m,n]

but it still wrong

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\network\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 703, in _add_inbound_node
    output_tensors[i]._keras_shape = output_shapes[i]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Please make a self-containing example that reproduces the problem, pseudocode is not good enough for this

Comment: Thank U for your answer , i will make a self-containing example,this is a
Innovative idea！